# How do I improve my php code to sorting column correctly on Datatable?

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

I'm trying to sort some columns on my Datatable using php code and ajax but it's not working properly. In my research i found some questions about this theme but unfortunately i didn't get the correct way to improve my php code for this. Below are the questions that i mentioned here:

1. [How can I improve this sorting code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557648/how-can-i-improve-this-sorting-code)
2. [Datatable sort by date correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800621/datatable-sort-by-date-correctly)
3. [Datatable: sorting not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857153/datatable-sorting-not-working)
4. [jQuery DataTables sorting is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862456/jquery-datatables-sorting-is-not-working)
5. [Jquery datatable Sort not working for Date Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836008/jquery-datatable-sort-not-working-for-date-column)
6. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

I have one table that call **users** where it contains the following structure:

```
id | first_name | last_name
______________________________
01 | Joseph     | Jackson
02 | Carlos     | Foster
03 | Natasha    | Fuller
04 | John       | Brandon
```

And i have one **index.php** page that display DataTable with the data above:

```
    <body>
        <div class="container box">
            <h1 align="center">PHP PDO Ajax CRUD with Data Tables </h1>
            <br />
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <br />
                <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="35%">First Name</th>
                            <th width="35%">Last Name</th>
                            <th width="10%">Edit</th>
                            <th width="10%">Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

In this **index.php** page, it has an Ajax code that call a php script that fetch data to display on Datatable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

    var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "order":[],
        "ajax":{
            url:"fetch.php",
            type:"POST"
        },
        "columnDefs":[
            {
                "targets":[2,3],
                "orderable":false,

            },
        ],

    });
    });
```

Below is the php script (**fetch.php**) that contain the code to fetch data and send to Ajax:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$query = '';
$output = array();
$query .= "SELECT * FROM users ";
if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
    $query .= 'WHERE first_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    $query .= 'OR last_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
}
if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}
if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
    $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row["first_name"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["last_name"];
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>';
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records(),
    "data"              =>  $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

As you can see above, Datatable display data and works fine but when i try to sort first_name column for example, the table not sorting correctly like A-Z or Z-A for example. In this link below, is based on my doubt and if you try to sort column you will observe that the sorting are not correct:

http://demo.webslesson.info/php-pdo-ajax-crud-datatables/

In this case, what can i do to improve my php or Ajax code to Datatable sorting correctly like A-Z/Z-A?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to write own implementation for Datatables on backend, use, for example yajra/laravel-datatables